# Android : Enlarging image size in new activity throws exception :  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4

Tags: android, imageview

I need to enlarge the image on click in new activity I am getting these images downloaded  from server and thus programmatically adding them in the main view and thus setting their ids explicitly. But my problem is that it is only picking the id of the last image and thus gives the exception.  I am using the following code for it in  the activity from which it is getting images. :

```
        private OnClickListener clickImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),FullImageActivity.class);

            fullScreenIntent.putExtra(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName(),imageId) ;
            ProfilePageNormalUser.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent); 
            System.out.println("going to fullimageactivity");

    }
};
```

and the following code where the image is to be enlarged.

```
       Intent intent = getIntent();
        int imageId = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName());
        imageView.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
        Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewEnlarged);
        myimage.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
        myimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

But it is giving me the following exception:

Edit : it is also giving me the following exception as in the stacktrace:

```
             11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable               to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emx.OnDaMove/com.emx.OnDaMove.FullImageActivity}:  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
           11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
           11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
          11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
         11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
          11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
         11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
      11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
         11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
       11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
          11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:817)
         11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:799)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at com.emx.OnDaMove.FullImageActivity.onCreate(FullImageActivity.java:25)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
           11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with the ResourceNotFoundException. Here is the line from your stack trace :

```
11-01 10:25:51.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5001): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
```

Make sure you're fetching the right image id in this line :

```
int imageId = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName());
```

Comment: yes the problem is here only. it is taking the same image id for all the images

Answer (score 0):

i can only venture a guess without seeing the stack-trace

```
findViewById(R.id.imageviewEnlarged);// maybe here?...
```

i am new at Android but the exception is telling you `ViewGroup$LayoutParams` wont go where you are putting it or you are trying to put something there that wont go there